# Set value ​in static inner class and write object to JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson

What is a better way to set the value of the variable c in class Nested and then write the nested object to JSON instead of how it was done in the main method?

```
    import lombok.Data;
    
    @Data
    public class Nested {
        private A a;
    
        @Data
        public static class A {
            private B b;
    
            @Data
            public static class B {
                private int c;
            }
        }
    }
```

```
import javax.json.bind.JsonbBuilder;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Nested nested = new Nested();
        Nested.A a = new Nested.A();
        Nested.A.B b = new Nested.A.B();
        b.setC(123);

        a.setB(b);
        nested.setA(a);

        System.out.println(JsonbBuilder.create().toJson(nested)); // Output: {"a":{"b":{"c":123}}}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just create both inner class `A`, `B` in `Nested` to reduce unnecessary  hierarchy.

```java
package com.example.demo;
package com.jason.empty;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Nested {
    private A a;

    @Data
    public static class A {
        private B b;
    }

    @Data
    public static class B {
        private int c;
    }
}
```

Note here `import com.example.demo.Nested.A` so that you can just use `A a = new A();` instead of `Nested.A a = new Nested.A();` to reduce the  complexity.

Jackson is a good JSON serialization/deserialization library for Java. The `ObjectMapper` API provides a straightforward way to parse and generate JSON:

```java
package com.example.demo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.example.demo.Nested.A;
import com.example.demo.Nested.B;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        B b = new B();
        b.setC(123);

        A a = new A();
        a.setB(b);

        Nested nested = new Nested();
        nested.setA(a);

        String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(nested);
        System.out.println(json);   // Output: {"a":{"b":{"c":123}}}
    }
}
```

### Moreover

You could use `@Accessors(chain = true)` to chain multiple `set` operations together in one statement.

```java
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.experimental.Accessors;

@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class Nested {
    private A a;

    @Data
    @Accessors(chain = true)
    public static class A {
        private B b;
    }

    @Data
    @Accessors(chain = true)
    public static class B {
        private int c;
    }
}
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    B b = new B().setC(123);
    A a = new A().setB(b);
    Nested nested = new Nested().setA(a);
    String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(nested);
    System.out.println(json);  // Output: {"a":{"b":{"c":123}}}
}
```